# How can receive multiple double values from switch case statements in multiple functions?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

So I declared 2 global variables.

```
static double y,y2,y3 = 0;
```

Also I have a picker that's shown when user selects textfield. 
On side this textfield is where the user enters input.

I want to simply be able to perform basic math operations with the two values.

I have functions SelectValue1 and SelectValue2 which have switch case statements in them each.
It takes the selectedchoice number from the picker view and uses that as the input for the switch case statement. I am trying to return the values of y and y2 from these respective functions. However only y is returning, and y2 is always zero.

```
-(double)SelectionValue1:(double)getPick{

    NSInteger rowpicked;
    rowpicked = [_Picker selectedRowInComponent:0];

    switch (rowpicked)
    {
        case 0:
            y = 41.0;
            break;
        case 1:
            y = 43.2;
            break;
        case 2:
            y = 43.5;
            break;
        case 3:
            y = 44.2;
            break;
    }
}

-(double)SelectionValue2:(double)getPick{

    NSInteger rowpicked;
    rowpicked = [_Picker selectedRowInComponent:0];

    switch (rowpicked)
    {
        case 0:
            y2 = 41.0;
            break;
        case 1:
            y2 = 43.2;
            break;
        case 2:
            y2 = 43.5;
            break;
        case 3:
            y2 = 44.2;
            break;
    }
}
```

And when I try to use the values in this calling method my result2 is zero.
Note: s1 and s2 are the values that the user entered.

```
result =[self doMath2:s1 secVal:y];
result2 =[self doMath:s2 secVal:y2];
```

I hope I explained somewhat properly.

Comment: 1. You don't show us your calling of `SelectionValue` and `SelectionValue2`, but I wonder if the latter is ever called. 2. Did you mean to have both of these refer to the same picker, or do you have two pickers? 3. Did you really mean to have `doMath2` use `y`, but `doMath` use `y2` (seems backwards). 4. Not a big deal, but you might want to consider following naming conventions whereby method and variable names begin with lowercase letter (e.g. `selectionValue`, not `SelectionValue`, `_picker`, not `_Picker`). 5. You haven't show `doMath` or `doMath2`, so we can't comment why `result` is 0.

Comment: - (double)doMath:(double)getval secVal:(double)tf{
    
    getval=(getval * tf)/23;
    return getval;
    
}

Comment: That seems innocuous enough. I'd suggest putting breakpoints or `NSLog` in `selectionValue2` and make sure it's getting called like you think it is. Maybe also add a `default` clause to your `switch` statements that will `NSLog` some warning if `rowpicked` doesn't return a value that you expected.

Comment: Never use floating point with a switch! Use an integer, and multiply if you need some precision.